# How to convert dates by working backwards from end of month?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I'd like to convert dates to weeks of month, but I'd like the weeks to be counted back to front, kind of. So if there are 5 weeks in a month, I'd like the last 7 days to be week 5, last 8 to 14 days to be week 4 and so on. The first week may or may not have 7 days.

Would love to hear your advice.

Comment: `(day_in_month - current_day) DIV 7`.

Answer (score 1):

With a date in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,0)-A1)/7,0)+1
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To reverse the order, use:

```
=4-ROUNDDOWN((DATE(YEAR(A95),MONTH(A95)+1,0)-A95)/7,0)+1
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The only thing is, I’d like your week 1 to be week 5, and week 5 to be week one. How would I go about reversing it like that?

Comment: @sonic99  See my **EDIT#1:**